# Add to Form Results from External Form

Tags: concrete5

Is there an API for adding to the Form Results that results from standard Forms are added to from an External Form?

I want to try avoid adding to the tables btform, btformanswers, etc. manually

Comment: What means external? On another server? Same server but outside of C5? In any case you could mimic a post request to a form block. If it's inside C5 you could work with the form block controllers `function action_submit_form()` directly.

Comment: What means external: the 'external form' block built right into C5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

See https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/blob/master/web/concrete/core/controllers/blocks/form.php#L354-L415 -- the core's form block updates the table manually.

As johjoh says, you could theoretically mimic a post to a form block, by instantiating it and then calling `action_submit_form()`, but that's just as fraught with difficulty, too... you'd have to keep the "form" in sync with your data, and possibly worry about the token and block ID and all that....

What's your exact use case? New block type? Some sort of external API? The form viewing interface in the dashboard is nice, but nothing that special. I think most people want to get data out of it, not in....

Comment: I've had to use an external form because of interaction with a mailing list API, I was hoping I could also keep this data within C5 alongside everything else the site receives through its standard C5 forms.

Comment: Thinking, sadly, I'll have to mark this answer as right. I really think this should be exposed though, it makes sense that if standard C5 form block results are stored in the dashboard then so are the results of non-standard external forms.

Comment: I think making an API for this would be complex due to the versioned and dynamic nature (possible questions change, there are 1 - n questions that answers need to be inserted for). Personally, lacking an API, I'd be comfortable inserting the applicable rows via  `tool`. Especially so cause this is the type of thing that only gets updated every 5 years.